# Join on Apache Ignite REST API

Tags: rest, ignite

Does anyone know if you can do a join using the REST API for Apache Ignite?  I have two objects, account and customer loaded to the Apache Ignite Server.  Both objects are loaded with data and stored in the cache as account object cache and customer object cache.  I am able to query both objects separately using the REST API, i.e.

http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=qryfldexe&pageSize=1000&cacheName=CustomerCache&qry=select+id+from+customer

http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=qryfldexe&pageSize=1000&cacheName=AccountCache&qry=select+id+from+account

However, I would like to execute a join on the account and customer cache.  Is this supported and if so, does anyone have any examples?  I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify one cache in the `cacheName`, and reference the second table in the `JOIN` via its schema name (by default it's the cache name). That's not unique to the REST API, Java API works in the same way.
The query should be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer AS c
JOIN AccountCache.Account AS a
WHERE c.id = a.customerId
```

Comment: We tried this: http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=qryfldexe&pageSize=1000&cacheName=CustomerCache&qry=select+id+full_name+from+Customer c+join+customer_account a+on+where+c.dw_id=a.dw_id but we get the response: {
    "successStatus": 1,
    "error": "Table \"CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT\" not found; SQL statement:\nselect id full_name from Customer c join \ncustomer_account a on where c.dw_id=a.dw_id [42102-195]",
    "response": null,
    "sessionToken": null
}

Comment: @Julie Where is this `customer_account` thing coming from? Do you have a table named like that? Could you please try the query I've shared in the answer?

Comment: In SQL it works, but Ignite creates the table as an object in the cache, if you query across tables it works using JDBC, but we are talking about doing a select across multiple cache objects.  The customer_account is the account object in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use qryfldexe:

For example, I create next caches:

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/file/t1704/ss1.java

It creates two caches with the same structure.

Now I am going to execute next command:

SELECT * FROM "mycache1".Value V1 join "mycache2".Value V2 on V1.key=V2.key

Let's use next converter to get URI string:

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Our command will be next:

SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22mycache1%22.Value%20V1%20join%20%22mycache2%22.Value%20V2%20on%20V1.key%3DV2.key

Run next in brouser:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=qryfldexe&pageSize=10&cacheName=mycache1&qry=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22mycache1%22.Value%20V1%20join%20%22mycache2%22.Value%20V2%20on%20V1.key%3DV2.key

Output:

```
{"successStatus":0,"error":null,"response":{"items":[[0,"Value 0",0,"Value 
0"],[1,"Value 1",1,"Value 1"],[2,"Value 2",2,"Value 2"],[3,"Value 
3",3,"Value 3"],[4,"Value 4",4,"Value 4"],[5,"Value 5",5,"Value 
5"],[6,"Value 6",6,"Value 6"],[7,"Value 7",7,"Value 7"],[8,"Value 
8",8,"Value 8"],[9,"Value 9",9,"Value 
9"]],"last":false,"queryId":10,"fieldsMetadata":[{"schemaName":"mycache1","typeName":"VALUE","fieldName":"KEY","fieldTypeName":"java.lang.Integer"},{"schemaName":"mycache1","typeName":"VALUE","fieldName":"VALUE","fieldTypeName":"java.lang.String"},{"schemaName":"mycache2","typeName":"VALUE","fieldName":"KEY","fieldTypeName":"java.lang.Integer"},{"schemaName":"mycache2","typeName":"VALUE","fieldName":"VALUE","fieldTypeName":"java.lang.String"}]},"sessionToken":null}
```